# How to use useEffect to change icon of a button on cursor hover in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to change the button icon on mouse hover with useEffect?

```
        <Button
          style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
          type="primary"
          icon={<img src={plusCart} />}
          onClick={addToBasket}
        />
```

Comment: You can use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` [events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

Comment: Use onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events with useState() hook for changing the icon on cursor hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to something like this:

```
const [icon, setIcon] = useState(plusCart)
<Button
  style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
  type="primary"
  icon={<img src={icon} />}
  onClick={addToBasket}
  onMouseEnter={() => setIcon(minusCart /**for example */)}
  onMouseLeave={() => setIcon(plusIcon /**for example */)}
/>;
```